# Count occurrences of each of certain words in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to count the number of occurrences of each of certain words in a data frame. I currently do it using `str.contains`:

```
a = df2[df2['col1'].str.contains("sample")].groupby('col2').size()
n = a.apply(lambda x: 1).sum()
```

Is there a method to match regular expression and get the count of occurrences? In my case I have a large dataframe and I want to match around 100 strings.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Update: Original answer counts those rows which contain a substring.

To count all the occurrences of a substring you can use [`.str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html):

```
In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame(['hello', 'world', 'hehe'], columns=['words'])

In [22]: df.words.str.count("he|wo")
Out[22]:
0    1
1    1
2    2
Name: words, dtype: int64

In [23]: df.words.str.count("he|wo").sum()
Out[23]: 4
```

---

The `str.contains` method accepts a regular expression:

```
Definition: df.words.str.contains(self, pat, case=True, flags=0, na=nan)
Docstring:
Check whether given pattern is contained in each string in the array

Parameters
----------
pat : string
    Character sequence or regular expression
case : boolean, default True
    If True, case sensitive
flags : int, default 0 (no flags)
    re module flags, e.g. re.IGNORECASE
na : default NaN, fill value for missing values.
```

For example:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame(['hello', 'world'], columns=['words'])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   words
0  hello
1  world

In [13]: df.words.str.contains(r'[hw]')
Out[13]:
0    True
1    True
Name: words, dtype: bool

In [14]: df.words.str.contains(r'he|wo')
Out[14]:
0    True
1    True
Name: words, dtype: bool
```

To count the occurences you can just sum this boolean Series:

```
In [15]: df.words.str.contains(r'he|wo').sum()
Out[15]: 2

In [16]: df.words.str.contains(r'he').sum()
Out[16]: 1
```

Comment: This is much neater and probably faster, obviating the need for ``get``.

Comment: @Andy Hayden: Lets say I want 'hello' count and 'word' count and print '"hello" count = 1', '"word" count = 1'?Can I do it in one line of code?

Comment: What about `word_regexs = [r'he', r'wo']` and then create a Series with `pd.Series((df.words.str.contains(r).sum() for r in word_regexs), word_regexs, name='count')` ?

Comment: This doesn't actually count occurrences. This counts the number of rows that contain a word, thus it won't work if the word can appear multiple times in a cell

Comment: There is a typo on substring instead of  subsctring. (first line)

Comment: `df.words.str.contains('he' or 'wo').sum()` also works. Also, if you want to count all occurrences of 'he' and 'wo' then use `df.words.str.count('he' or 'wo').sum()`

Answer (score 7):

You can use `value_count` function.

```py
import pandas as pd

# URL to .csv file
data_url = 'https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/carData/Arrests.csv'
# Reading the data
df = pd.read_csv(data_url, index_col=0)
```

[image]

```py
# pandas count distinct values in column
df['sex'].value_counts()
```

[image]

Source: [link](https://www.marsja.se/pandas-count-occurrences-in-column-unique-values/)

Answer (score 6):

To count the total number of matches, use `s.str.match(...).str.get(0).count()`.

If your regex will be matching several unique words, to be tallied individually, use
`s.str.match(...).str.get(0).groupby(lambda x: x).count()`

It works like this:

```
In [12]: s
Out[12]: 
0    ax
1    ay
2    bx
3    by
4    bz
dtype: object
```

The `match` string method handles regular expressions...

```
In [13]: s.str.match('(b[x-y]+)')
Out[13]: 
0       []
1       []
2    (bx,)
3    (by,)
4       []
dtype: object
```

...but the results, as given, are not very convenient. The string method `get` takes the matches as strings and converts empty results to NaNs...

```
In [14]: s.str.match('(b[x-y]+)').str.get(0)
Out[14]: 
0    NaN
1    NaN
2     bx
3     by
4    NaN
dtype: object
```

...which are not counted.

```
In [15]: s.str.match('(b[x-y]+)').str.get(0).count()
Out[15]: 2
```

Comment: :Thanks Allan, problem with me is not taking the count, how about matching regex..Andy has provided a neat answer as you have agreed..:)