# Pandas: Count frequency of multiple words(strings), using regex, in a column

Tags: python, pandas

So I tried implementing the answer to this question:

[Count occurrences of certain words in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573814/count-occurrences-of-certain-words-in-pandas-dataframe)

but it is not doing what I want.

So let me try explaining the scenario with a dataframe output:

```
      Date                | Log

1     2012-02-02 02:10:01 | GET: /www/file1.php
2     2012-02-02 03:11:04 | GET: /www/img/file5.php
3     ... ... ...
```

So that is how the dataframe looks and from first-glance, you can tell it is a log file.

Anyways, this is the regex I used: `\B./[\w./$-]+` (which works perfectly and isn't the issue) The regex finds just the /file/path , which is what I want.

---

My goal is to get a frequency output like so:

```
                      | /www/file1.php | /etc/gmn/file.css | http/trw/file.js
Date

2012-02-02 02:10:01   |        1       |         0         |       1
2012-02-02 03:11:04   |        0       |         1         |       1
2012-02-05 06:22:04   |        1       |         1         |       1
```

My goal is to count the frequencies of each file occurring and then be able to call onto those files (via a column name OR some alternative option).

As you know from logs like this, there could be hundreds of files, but I need to know the frequency of each file appearing (in the log file itself).

Knowing the frequency of the most-called files will help me determine which files I can place on a CDN (this is just an example of what I *can* do with this type of information, in case someone thinks it is pointless - although I do NOT want a solution that is NOT pandas-based)

Something I tried that didn't work:

```
df.groupby('Date')['Log'].apply(lambda x: x[x.str.contains(r'\B./[\w./$-]+')].count())
```

Any other suggestions (similar to above) would be appreciated.

Comment: I think we need to see more detail about why the solution you tried didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Classic case of pivot. First, let's introduce a count column, then create a pivot table. Let's ignore your regex, since that is not the issue; just apply it to the column beforehand.

```
df["Count"] = 1
df.pivot("Date", "Log", "Count").fillna(0)
```

In the case there are rows with the same date and log (maybe you will bin later on, e.g. just keep the date, not the time), you need to group first.

```
df.groupby(["Date", "Log"], as_index=False).sum().pivot("Date", "Log", "Count").fillna(0)
```