# Counting occurrence of multiple words Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, feature-extraction

I am quite new to Python, so sorry for my not-knowing. I want to create, for example, a table in which the rows are documents and the columns are labels. A document feature matrix if you will. Every label represents an arbitrary number of words (usually 1, 2 or 3 words). They are stored in a dict:

```
regexDict =    
{u'item_4278': [u'occupational', u'position', u'job'],
u'item_4279': [u'job', u'blue', u'collar'],
u'item_4276': [u'job', u'civil', u'service'], 
...}
```

Now, I have a number of documents (represented as strings in a df) and I want to find out how often the words from one label appear in a document.

For the following:

```
df = 
doc    text
doc1    My job is in civil service. I love my job blabla civil bla bla service bla. 
doc2    My job is in civil service. It is a job that you call blue collar. 
doc3    This is a document completely unrelated to the items.
```

I would like to count the amount of times the values occur somewhat close to each other in a document, for example with this regex I created:

```
occupational\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?position\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?job\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?
```

Desired output:

```
        item_4278    item_4279    item_4276
Doc 1       0            0            2
Doc 2       0            1            1
Doc 3       0            0            0
```

**Edit**: If only 1 or 2 words appear in the document, it should get a score of 0. It is important that all words appear in the document! :) By somewhat close to each other, I mean that if it says "This is a text. These sentences don't contain interesting words. My job is in civil service. The previous sentence does contain interesting words", 'job' 'civil' and 'service' appear quite close to each other in the entire document, so the document gets a score of 1 for item_4276.

Right now, all I got is this, but it is far from satisfactory:

```
testdic = {
'item_1': r'occupational\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?position\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?job\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?', 
'item_2': r'job\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?blue\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?collar\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?',
'item_3': r'job\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?civil\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?service\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?'
}

total = []
for key, item in testdic.iteritems():
    series = df.text.str.count(item)
    series = series.rename(key)
    total.append(series)
    total2 = pd.concat(total, axis=1)
```

In the end I would like to filter the matrix with scores to only have counts of between 5-10 for every document. 
So all in all, written compactly (but obviously not working-ly :-) ):

```
def interesting_items(doc, regexDict):
    for value in regexDict.values():
        df.loc[df['doc'] == doc, 'text'].iloc[0].str.count(value)
return count per regexDict.keys() if count > 5 and count < 10
```

Comment: It would seem you are using `pandas`, you might want to tag it so pandas user will be a better help. :)

Comment: I will, thanks a lot for your help. It helped me a lot in my thinking process and in learning how to use SO :-)

Comment: All items (like blue, collar and job) should be present in the document? What if only 2 of 3 words are present? Also what do you mean by "somewhat close to each other"?

Comment: If only 1 or 2 words appear in the document, it should get a score of 0. It is important that all words appear in the document! :) By somewhat close to each other, I mean that if it says "This is a text. These sentences don't contain interesting words. My job is in civil service. The previous sentence does contain interesting words", 'job' 'civil' and 'service' appear quite close to each other in the entire document, so the document gets a score of 1 for item_4276.

Comment: You might want to look at this. This might even be a duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573814/count-occurrences-of-certain-words-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Amazing!!! I'll try and delete this post if it works.

Comment: How do you decide to give score of 1 versus 2? Why item_4276 gets value of 2 for doc1 and 1 for doc2?

Comment: Because 'job', 'civil' and 'service' appear close to each other TWICE in doc 1, but only once in doc 2. @rnso

Comment: 'close' is very subjective.

Comment: Absolutely true :)

Answer (score 0):

One can use following function to determine if all words in a list are present in sent text:

```
def allpresent(text, wordlist):
    for word in wordlist:
        if text.find(word) == -1: 
            return False
    return True
```

Following code can then be used to get new dataframe:

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame(index=df.doc.tolist(), columns=labels.keys())
for rownum in range(len(df)):
    txt = df.text[rownum]
    for k,v in labels.items():
        if allpresent(df.text[rownum], v):
            newdf.loc[df.doc[rownum], k] = 1
        else:
            newdf.loc[df.doc[rownum], k] = 0

print(newdf)
```

Output:

```
     item_4278 item_4279 item_4276
doc1         0         0         1
doc2         0         1         1
doc3         0         0         0
```

Comment: Hi @rnso, thanks for your comment! As said, I'd like to count how often the combination of words appears in a document. Let me edit my question with what I have thus far!