# Daily Mentions of a Word

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, word-count

I have the following df, containing daily articles from different sources:

```
print(df)

Date         content

2018-11-01    Apple Inc. AAPL 1.54% reported its fourth cons...
2018-11-01    U.S. stocks climbed Thursday, Apple is a real ...
2018-11-02    GONE are the days when smartphone manufacturer...
2018-11-03    To historians of technology, the story of the ...
2018-11-03    Apple Inc. AAPL 1.54% reported its fourth cons...
2018-11-03    Apple is turning to traditional broadcasting t...

(...)
```

I would like to compute the total number of **daily mentions** - hence aggregating by Date - of the word "Apple". How can I create "final_df"?

```
print(final_df) 

    2018-11-01    2
    2018-11-02    0
    2018-11-03    2
    (...)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count occurrences of certain words in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573814/count-occurrences-of-certain-words-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html) for new `Series`, aggregate by column `df['Date']` with `sum`:

```
df1 = df['content'].str.count('Apple').groupby(df['Date']).sum().reset_index(name='count')
print (df1)
         Date  count
0  2018-11-01      2
1  2018-11-02      0
2  2018-11-03      2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the different dates, use [`str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to count the occurrences of `Apple` and aggregate with the `sum` to get the amount of counts in each group:

```
df.groupby('Date').apply(lambda x: x.content.str.count('Apple').sum())
                  .reset_index(name='counts')

      Date     counts
0 2018-11-01       2
1 2018-11-02       0
2 2018-11-03       2
```

Comment: I appreciated your answer for its simplicity and readability, but I prefer to create a dataframe, instead of a series, in a single line. Thank you.

Comment: Not particularly;

Comment: Modified the answer to do so adding `reset_index`

Answer (score 0):

You can try alternate solution with  [str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `groupby` function without using `sum` all along.

```
>>> df
         Date                                         content
0  2018-11-01  Apple Inc. AAPL 1.54% reported its fourth cons
1  2018-11-01   U.S. stocks climbed Thursday, Apple is a real
2  2018-11-02  GONE are the days when smartphone manufacturer
3  2018-11-03   To historians of technology, the story of the
4  2018-11-03  Apple Inc. AAPL 1.54% reported its fourth cons
5  2018-11-03  Apple is turning to traditional broadcasting t
```

Solutions:

```
df.content.str.contains("Apple").groupby(df['Date']).count().reset_index(name="count")

         Date  count
0  2018-11-01      2
1  2018-11-02      1
2  2018-11-03      3


# df["content"].str.contains('Apple',case=True,na=False).groupby(df['Date']).count()
```

Comment: @jezrael, not deliberately , however i changed my answer :-)  hope you wont mind.