# What's the difference between these two ways to calculate the number of occurrences of two words in a text column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to pandas, and I'm learning it on Kaggle now.

Here is an exercise asking about to **find the number of occurrences of two words** in the `description` column.

I found the first statement from StackOverflow, but the second one is the correct answer. What's the reason for this different result?

##### 1. Found from StackOverflow

```
tropical = reviews.description.str.count("tropical").sum()
fruity = reviews.description.str.count("fruity").sum()
descriptor_counts = pd.Series([tropical,fruity])
```

`

##### 2. The correct answer

```
tropical = reviews.description.map(lambda desc: 'tropical' in desc).sum()
fruity = reviews.description.map(lambda desc: 'fruity' in desc).sum()
descriptor_counts = pd.Series([tropical, fruity],index=['tropical','fruity'])
```

The first result is `[3703, 9259]`
The second result is `[3607, 9090]`

Update! The original question is:
Create a Series descriptor_counts counting how many times each of these two words appears in the description column in the dataset.

Comment: I suspect because the first one counts the number of occurrences of the strings in each description, and then sums them. The second one maps to True if the string is present in the description and then sums them (boolean values convert to integers for addition - eg. `True + True == 2`).

Comment: The difference is `.str.count` can handle multiple occurrences of word in each entry, whereas `.map(lambda desc: 'tropical' in desc)` only counts the boolean True/False for each entry, so multiple occurrences will only count as 1.

Comment: Related: [Count occurrences of each of certain words in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573814/count-occurrences-of-each-of-certain-words-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example

[image]

The first code counts tropical to be 5 and fruity to be 4. It counts repetitions of the word in the same description.
So, the result would be `[5,4]` in this example.

The second code counts topical to be 4 and fruity to be 3. It counts the presence of the word in each description (`if tropical in description`). Once you find it, it counts as one no matter how many more are in that description.
So, the result would be `[4,3]`.

So, I feel the question is wrong. If the question is about the number of occurrences of the two words, in this example `[5,4]` should be correct (in your case `[3703,9259]`). If the question asks in how many descriptions each word occurs, then you are counting the descriptions by using `if word in description`. So, check the question one more time.

Comment: Thanks for giving this example! I go back and checked the question, it says: ' Create a Series descriptor_counts counting how many times each of these two words appears in the description column in the dataset.' I might be misunderstanding the question.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is less because it's only getting the values that **are** `'tropical'` or `'fruity'`.

So:

```
>>> s='a'
>>> s=='a'
True
```

But the second one is getting the values that **contain** `'tropical'` or `'fruity'`, so the above:

```
>>> s='ab'
>>> s=='a'
False
```

So it does:

```
>>> s='ab'
>>> 'a' in s
True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count1, count2 = 0, 0

for i in description.iteritems():
    if "fruity" in i[0]:
        count1 += i[1]
    if "tropical" in i[0]:
        count2 += i[1]

descriptor_counts = pd.Series(data = {"fruity": count1, "tropical": count2},
                          index = ["tropical", "fruity"])
```

Recently I was going through the same problem and this would be my solution without using a "lambda expression"

Answer (score 0):

This is how I could solve it and got the correct answer:

```
n_trop = reviews['description'].str.contains('tropical').sum()
n_fruit = reviews['description'].str.contains('fruity').sum()
descriptor_counts = pd.Series([n_trop,n_fruit], index=('tropical','fruity')) 
print(descriptor_counts)
```

Comment: This answer does not address OP's question.