# How to search word in column A and count it based on column B in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe based on Text, Date and Author like this:

```
TEXT               Author               Date
This is a Cat       Jane                 1.01.1997
This is a Dog       Sara                 1.02.2009
I have a cat        Lesner               5.07.2001
```

So, I want to write a script like this: For example I want to search word "Cat" and then it should count "Cat" based on Date column:

and the Output should look like this:

```
Date        count
1.01.1997    1
1.02.2009    0
5.07.2001    1
```

Comment: Use [`pandas.str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count occurrences of certain words in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573814/count-occurrences-of-certain-words-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) with ignore lower and upper cases, but also are counts words like `cation`, `locate` because contains subtring `cat`:

```
import re

df['count'] = df['TEXT'].str.count('cat', flags=re.I)
```

For prevent counts subtrings is possible add word boundaries `\b\b`:

```
df['count'] = df['TEXT'].str.count(r'\bcat\b', flags=re.I)
```

---

```
print (df)
            TEXT  Author       Date  count
0  This is a Cat    Jane  1.01.1997      1
1  This is a Dog    Sara  1.02.2009      0
2   I have a cat  Lesner  5.07.2001      1
```

Last filter by list of columns:

```
df1 = df[['Date','count']]
print (df1)
        Date  count
0  1.01.1997      1
1  1.02.2009      0
2  5.07.2001      1
```

EDIT:

> i am just curious that is it possible that we able to count "nunique" because for example if cat comes twice in the sentence then it will count as 2 but i just need to check if the word "Cat" is available. So, the output should be 0 or 1.

Then is better use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and cast to integer for `True->1` and `False->0` map:

```
df['exist'] = df['TEXT'].str.contains(r'\bcat\b', flags=re.I).astype(int)
print (df)

            TEXT  Author       Date  exist
0  This is a Cat    Jane  1.01.1997      1
1  This is a Dog    Sara  1.02.2009      0
2   I have a cat  Lesner  5.07.2001      1
```

If need both columns is posible use [`Series.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html):

```
df['count'] = df['TEXT'].str.count('cat', flags=re.I)
df['exist'] = df['count'].clip(upper=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It completely what i wanted but i am just curious that is it possible that we able to count "nunique" because for example if cat comes twice in the sentence then it will count as 2 but i just need to check if the word "Cat" is available. So, the output should be 0 or 1.

Comment: amzing - Thanks alot :)