# Python Get Count of instances of string in column using XLSX data

Tags: python, pandas

High Level Scenario of two data items in each file

I have a CSV file that I write with historical data

```
server,share,access,link
myserv,myshare,READ,\\myserv\myshare
myserv1,myshare23,READ,\\myserv\myshare
myserv1,myshare23,READ,\\myserv\myshare
myserv,myshare,READ,\\myserv\myshare
```

I have a xlsx file that is a snapshot of current state

```
server,share,access,link,instances
myserv,myshare,READ,\\myserv\myshare
myserv1,myshare23,READ,\\myserv\myshare
```

What I would like to do is go through the xlsx file and add the the occurrences by reading the csv link column and give a count example below of end result. This seems so difficult to do in python and just don't understand why. PowerShell I could do this in three lines, but I'm **trying** to learn python.

```
server,share,access,link,instances
myserv,myshare,READ,\\myserv\myshare, **2**
myserv1,myshare23,READ,\\myserv\myshare, **2**
```

Code so far below

```
import pandas
import os

# Read csv file use pandas module.
def read_csv_file_by_pandas(csv_file):
    data_frame = None
    if(os.path.exists(csv_file)):
        data_frame = pandas.read_csv(csv_file,sep=';')   
    return data_frame

# Write pandas.DataFrame object to a csv file.
def write_to_csv_file_by_pandas(csv_file_path, data_frame):
    data_frame.to_csv(csv_file_path)


# Write pandas.DataFrame object to an excel file.
def write_to_excel_file_by_pandas(excel_file_path, data_frame):
    excel_writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(excel_file_path, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df = read_csv_file_by_pandas('history.csv')
    data_frame['link'] = '\\\\' + data_frame['server'] + '\\' + data_frame['share'] + '\\'
    for index, row in data_frame.iterrow():
        row["times"] = df['link'].str.count("\\\\" + row["server"] + "\\" + row['share'] +"\\")

    data_frame.to_excel(excel_writer, 'Data', index=False)
    excel_writer.save()
    print(excel_file_path + ' has been created.') 

def write_history_csv_by_panadas(data_frame):
    data_frame['link'] = '\\\\' + data_frame['server'] + '\\' + data_frame['share']   
    data_frame.to_csv('history.csv', mode='a',header=True,sep=';',index=False)
    print('history.csv' + ' has been updated.')

df = read_csv_file_by_pandas('data.csv')
write_history_csv_by_panadas(df)
write_to_excel_file_by_pandas('data.xlsx', df )
```

Comment: Is there a reason you chose Pandas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count occurrences of certain words in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573814/count-occurrences-of-certain-words-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: You are reading a csv and updating/modifying an xlsx? Or are you reading the csv and creating an xlsx?

Comment: I'm 100% new to python, just saw Pandas as a easy option, open to whatever.

I'm taking a csv and creating a historical CSV of all records and creating a onetime snapshot from the source csv with \\server\share and count

Comment: What are you having a problem with?.. What is the question? How is your solution deficient?

Comment: Basically I have no idea how to do the following.
1. Read through xlsx and do the following

2. foreach row read these columns Server+Share

3. search for Server+Share in column X in csv 

4. Count the occurences of Server+Share

5. add the count to xlsx row currently working on under column Y