# How to count a specific word in a Pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas

lets say I have a data frame, which is called 'df',
this dataframe has a column called 'JobTitle'.

Now I want to count how many times the word 'Chief' is in my 'JobTitles' column.

I found a way to count if a JobTitle is == Chief, but most of the JobTitles which includes Chief have more than the word Chief (for example: Chief President) and my solution isn't working.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count occurrences of certain words in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573814/count-occurrences-of-certain-words-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

This will show the count number.

```
df[df['JobTitle'].str.contains('Chief')].count()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
len(df[df.JobTitle.str.contains('Chief')])
```

`.str.contains` returns a Boolean series indicating whether the value contains "Chief"