# Is there a non-looping way to perform text searching in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, n-gram

I have a huge list of ngrams to search. I want to know what frequency they have on my historic dataframe and the mean of a numeric variable that I have on my historic. I have a really really ugly way of doing it (that works), but as the list of ngrams is huge, it's really slow.

I am trying to avoid doing the loop, as I guess is the main reason of my velocity problem, but I don't see how I can do it.

Any idea?

```
output = pd.DataFrame()

ngrams = ['ngram1', 'ngram2', 'ngram3', ..., 'ngram350000']

for i in list(ngrams):
    temp = pd.DataFrame(data={'ngram' : [i],
                              'count' : historic_df['text_variable'].str.contains(i, na=False).sum(),
                              'mean' : historic_df[historic_df['text_variable'].str.contains(i, na=False)]['numeric_variable'].mean()})
    output = pd.concat([output, temp], axis=0)
```

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a regular expression. In brief, `regex = "|".join(ngrams)` (assuming none of your `ngrams` contain regex special characters; try `"|".join(re.escape(x) for x in ngrams)` if you are not sure) and then `re.findall(regex, (your text))`. This will not find overlapping matches, though (which can be done, too, but somewhat painfully).

Comment: Hi @tripleee. Not sure if I am understanding you, but with that idea sounds that I would get if each rows has any of the ngrams or not, right? Instead of the info founded in each ngram separately.

Comment: `findall` returns all the matching strings; but as previously noted, it will not find `bc` if you search for `"ab|bc|cd"` in `"abcd"`. I'm not familiar enough with Pandas to show you how to do this in a dataframe, unfortunately; but it should not be hard to google.

Comment: how about this option? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17574265/8805842
just keep in mind, if you have HUGE amount of rows, avoid iterating/looping.
Pandas usually have much better vectorised solutions

Answer (score 0):

Try DataFrame.apply()

```python
def func(x):
    temp = pd.DataFrame(data={'ngram' : [i],
                              'count' : historic_df['text_variable'].str.contains(i, na=False).sum(),
                              'mean' : historic_df[historic_df['text_variable'].str.contains(i, na=False)]['numeric_variable'].mean()})
    output = pd.concat([output, temp], axis=0)
    return x

output = pd.DataFrame()

ngrams = pd.DataFrame({'ngram':['ngram1', 'ngram2', 'ngram3', ..., 'ngram350000']})

ngrams.apply(func)
```